# VBA script to cleanup deleted folder not working

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to move emails in the deleted folder that are older than 21 days containing "Xtremevbtalk" in the subject line. Here is the code:

```
Sub emptydeletedfolder()
Dim oSource As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oTarget As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Date21days As Date
Dim ItemsOverDays As Outlook.Items

Dim DateToCheck As String

Date21days = DateAdd("d", -21, Now())
Date21days = Format(Date21days, "mm/dd/yyyy")


Set oSource = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
Set oTarget = oSource.Folders("_old")

DateToCheck = "[Received] <= """ & Date21days & """"

Set ItemsOverDays = oSource.Items.Restrict(DateToCheck)

For i = ItemsOverDays.Count To 1 Step -1

If ItemsOverDays.Item(itm.Subject, "Xtremevbtalk") > 0 Then
    ItemsOverDays.Item(i).Move oTarget
    End
End If
Next

Set ItemsOverDays = Nothing
Set oTarget = Nothing
Set oSource = Nothing
End Sub
```

As I step through the code, it fails at line: If ItemsOverDays.Item(itm.Subject, "Xtremevbtalk") > 0 Then

The code runs fine without the if statement, removing all emails older than 21 days, not sure how to write this line, any advice would be most helpful

Thanks
G

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: that is because Items does not take two parameters, only 1 which is the index of the item. ->>>ItemsOverDays.Item(itm.Subject, "Xtremevbtalk") that line is wrong

Comment: It says wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. How would I write the line so that it checks the subject of the email?

Answer (score 0):

Try

If InStr(ItemsOverDays.Item(I).Subject, "Xtremevbtalk") > 0 Then